# Flatten Array Result of Symfony Doctrine Array Result

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

With a repository I got an array result (each array is an entity object) like this:

```
array(
  0 => object of type entity,
  1 => another object of type entity,
  2 => another object of type entity,
)
```

each object has some properties like id and name, etc.
But I what I want is flatten the whole array only with the id of each object.

What I want is this (flatten the array only with ID's):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 23
)
```

> My solution:

```
$ids = array_map($transform = function($entity) {
    if ($entity instanceof Entity) {
       return $entity->getId();
    }
 }, $myGreatDbResult);
```

My solution is working but is there a better way to get this result?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Once you get the array of identifiers `[0 => ['id' => 1], 1 => ['id' => 6], 2 => ['id' => 26] ...]` just you have to use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function to get the values from a single column in the input array:

```
$ids = array_column($result, 'id');
```

> Since PHP 5.5.0

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 23
    ...
)
```

Comment: it is now possible to use:
$query->getSingleColumnResult()
or
$query->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_SCALAR_COLUMN)

Answer (score 1):

The result you are getting:

```
array(
  0 => object of type entity,
  1 => another object of type entity,
  2 => another object of type entity,
)
```

Is probably a result of `findBy()` or `getResult()` methods. To achieve what you want you will need to create your own query and do something like this:

```
$result = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:Entity', 'e') //your entity
    ->select('e.id') //your id field
    ->getQuery()
    ->getScalarResult();
```

This will give you array you're expecting

Comment: It will give an array `[0 => ['id' => 1], 1 => ['id' => 6], 2 => ['id' => 26] ...]` so array_map still needed.

Comment: did you try `getScalarResult` instead of `getArrayResult` ? I edited an answer

Comment: Yes, `getScalarResult` gives the same array as `getArrayResult`

Comment: Still, this approach is better as it avoids unnecessarily hydrating the objects.

Comment: the scalarResult will give me an associative array. But not the expected or wished result. When I combine your solution with the answer of yonel I got my wished result.

Comment: This does not work: in my case, it returns an array of arrays

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you can now simply use

```
$qb->getSingleColumnResult()
```

Which returns a numeric array with each column value (omitting the column name etc)

As per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660646/flatten-array-result-of-symfony-doctrine-array-result#comment126466856_39661621) from user [KicksheepSon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9328718/kicksheepson)

Answer (score -1):

The best practices are to use the symfony native method, so as Tomasz Madeyski says, Use

```
...->getQuery()->getScalarResult()
```

You can also get it that way by doing

```
->getQuery()->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)
```

A good practice also is to create the method INTO the repository class and make it hybrid by giving the choice of the two types, for exemple :.

```
public function findAll($hydratedArray = false)
{
    $query = $this  ->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->leftJoin('p.company', 'c')
                    ->select('p')
                    ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');

    $result = $hydratedArray    ? $query
                                    ->leftJoin('p.series', 's')
                                    ->leftJoin('s.variety', 'v')
                                    ->addSelect('c', 's', 'v')
                                    ->getQuery()
                                    ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY) // or getScalarResult()
                              : $query->getQuery()->getResult();

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: This does not work: in my case, it returns an array of arrays